# Jboss 5.1.0 EJB Security (unauthenticated principal via JNDI)

Tags: security, ejb-3.0, jndi, jboss5.x, jaas

How do you secure remote EJBs from unauthenticated principal in JBoss-5.1.0.GA application server? After configuring my ejb security I can still access the remote EJBs with a JNDI lookup without principal and credentials passed in? This is a security risk. Essentially I want to disable all unauthenticated JNDI lookup on remote EJBs.

**Here is my *server/conf/login-config.xml* configruation:**

```
       <application-policy name="<my security domain name>">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">         
            <module-option name="dsJndiName">**java:jdbc/<my datasource name>**</module-option>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery"><my users query></module-option>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery"><my roles query></module-option>
            <module-option name="debug">true</module-option>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>
```

**Here is my *jboss.xml* configruation in my ejb jar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC
"-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 5.0//EN"
"http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_5_0.dtd">
  <jboss>
 <security-domain><my security domain name from login-config></security-domain>
  </jboss>
```

**Here is how i do a a JNDI lookup to access my beans as a client**
*Note the principal and credentials are not being passed in to the context*

```
    Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
     props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");      
    props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");      

    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:1099"); 
    //props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,""); 
    //props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"");   
    ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    ctx.lookup("<earname>/<ejb interface definition>/remote">
```

**What is the issue?**
When no/wrong principal/credentials are passed the user is authenticated as an anonymous principal and has full access to the remote EJBs via JNDI

**What I tried already to fix the issue:**

- i deleted the following line from all login modules in my *server/conf/login-config.xml* but it had no effect

  ```
  <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">anonymous</module-option>
  ```
- i deleted following line from *server/conf/jboss-service.xml* thinking it will resolve the issue, but it had no effect

  ```
   <attribute name="DefaultUnauthenticatedPrincipal">anonymous</attribute>
  ```
- i deleted application policy "client-login" from login-config.xml that is in there by default since i am using a DatabaseLoginModule
- My **jboss-ejb-policy** and **jboss-web-policy** in *server/depoly/security/security-policies-jboss-beans.xml* are extending my DatabaseLoginModule policy in login-config.xml
- I have no security related annotations in my ejb classes/interfaces

**Other things to note**

- I tested this scenario in Jboss-as-7.1.1.final and i get **EjbAccessException: invalid User** which is correct (you add this to the jboss-ejb3.xml it will secure all EJBs via the security domain)

  ```
  <assembly-descriptor>
     <s:security>
       <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
       <s:security-domain><security domain name here></s:security-domain>
     </s:security>
   </assembly-descriptor>
  ```
- the issue here is NOT authorization but authentications all ejb security annotations do not help
- what i want to do is prevent the anonymous principal completely from making JNDI call
- I have enabled TRACE logging on org.jboss.security and i can see that when ever i call the JNDI i get the following hit in the logs

  ```
  Principal: anonymous:callerRunAs=null:callerRunAs=null:ejbRestrictionEnforcement=false:ejbVersion=null];    policyRegistration=org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossPolicyRegistration@1f51a2f;
  ```
- I have verified all my configurations work and the DatabaseLoginModule works when i use the programmatic login through WebAuthetication
- Even when passing the initial context a valid principal/credential from database the anonymous principal is used indicating that the principal/credential is not even processed by the context
- I can probably secure my EJBs through @RolesAllowed @DeclareRoles ... but like i mentioned this would be an authorization concern not authentication and also if I have many roles and EJBs this would not be good as far as maintainability

How can I disable/prevent unauthenticated anonymous JNDI lookup for the entire application like it automatically does in JBoss 7.1.1? I know I can upgrade my application server as one solution but I don't have the option to do so.  This should be possible and easy to do in Jboss 5.1.0. but i have looked for the answer everywhere and I can't find it? Thanks for your help.